# How can I draw this picture in PS

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am an novice.

I want to draw this picture
[image]

But I meet a problem
 I found a heart outline image from the internet and dropped on my ps file. When I was trying to fill this heart with a pure color, it becomes something like this 
[image]

Comment: why down vote? I am happy to learn.

Comment: I down voted because this question shows no effort.

Comment: @Scott hi there, I spent almost 1 hour to fill in the pure red color inside this beautiful heart. I tried brush, and clicked all the possible buttons, but none of them worked for me. I hope this shows my efforts to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you filling using the paint bucket (G key) or using a brush?... The pixelated effect of your fill looks like your layer is on the dissolve blend mode or that you used one of the airbrushes to fill the shape.

This particular shape lends itself to being created in Illustrator. However, if you were to create it in Photoshop you would use the pen tool in combination with the shape tools.

Comment: thanks mate, I have solved it by clicking around and I didn't know what I clicked but it now fills in the pure color in it. I will give it a try and keep you posted. cheers